# py2exe missing module pyodbc

Tags: python, py2exe

my python script uses pyodbc module.
When I create setup.py script it failed to compile and throws the error:

```
 raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
portError: No module named pyodbc
```

What is wrong with my setup.py script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console=['accession.py'],
    options={
        'py2exe': {
            'includes': 'pyodbc'
            }
        }
    )
```

Thanks in advance
P.S.
Sorry ... but I was wrong in my comments:
1. I do have 2 Python installation and I deleted one i.e. ipython and I have only Python 2.7 now
2. I do have pyodbc installed because I could use it when I run just 'plain' python script  ( without py2exe)
3. I could check that it's installed like this:

> yolk -l
>       bottle          - 0.12.7       - active
>       pip 1.5.6 has no metadata
>       py2exe          - 0.6.10       - active
>       pyodbc          - 3.0.7        - active
>   What else could be the problem?
>   Thanks again

Comment: Do you actually have `pyodbc` installed? (And is it possible that you have two different Python installations, one of which has `pyodbc` installed, while the other doesn't?)

Comment: hi abameret,
you are correct: I have 2 Python installations: ipython and Python 2.7. I just checked that 2.7 has pyodbc but ipython does not. I did my development using 2.7 and used py2exe using 2.7 as well. What would you recommend me to do to fix it?, Thanks

Comment: IPython isn't a separate installation, it's a package that installs into your existing Python installation. I mean having two different Python directories (like `C:\Python27` and `D:\Python27`), each with their own Python.exe, site-packages folder, etc.

Comment: - a artery, in my case it was 2 different installations in 2 different directories.  ipython did not have pyodbc and it was first in system path. After I fixed the path I did not have the issue with odbc because my program started to use only Python 2.7 which had that module. Thanks again for heads up

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by confusion between two separate Python installations.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to close this as you asked (although I had a hard time coming up with a close reason). But don't post a request for closing as an answer. Only post answers as answers. If you don't have enough rep to close your own question, post a _comment_ asking others to do it (or flag it if you think it needs a mod's attention, but usually it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that your python script uses pyodbc module, but I am not sure if you have properly installed it. Try `pip install pyodbc` or `pip install https://pyodbc.googlecode.com/files/pyodbc-3.0.6.zip` to install this module if you do not yet have it installed.

Comment: -XYZ927
After I've put Python 2.7 in front in PATH variable I did not have an issue to compile it.
The other issue is that my program is using Bottle and along with 'main' python script it uses 2 template files .tpl and I don't know how to include it in setup.py.
Likely will need to open another ticket for it. what do you think? and thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry for causing the noise. After I installed pyodbc again I don't have the issue any more. Still not clear why it's so flaky and had to install it again and now it looks like this:
>yolk -l
pip 1.5.6 has no metadata
py2exe          - 0.6.10       - active
pyodbc          - 3.0.7        - non-active
pyodbc          - 3.0.7        - non-active
pyodbc          - 3.0.7        - active
pyodbc          - 3.0.7        - active
setuptools 5.4.1 has no metadata

Comment: So did you get it to work using one of those two install commands I gave?  Let me know if there are any other issues.

Comment: Hi. I did not have to install the module. It was already there and I had only to use 'right' Python. Now I do not have problem with that module anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

setup.py code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console=['yourfile.py'],
    options = { "py2exe": { "includes": "decimal, datetime" } }
)
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.